# Error when hovering over my top-bar

Tags: css, hover, border

As you see in the following image: (I'm not allowed to post images so I've uploaded them on Twitpic, since they're very useful to understand my question)

http://twitpic.com/brvzas

I'm trying to change the top-border colour when hovering over a component of my top-bar. The problem is that everything gets shifted out the bar..I'd like just to change the colour of the margin without shifting anything..I'd like to get this effect (here the border is the bottom one, it's just to make you understand what I'd like to do):

http://twitpic.com/brvzse

I've modified the CSS file in this way:

```
.top-bar [...]{ background: black; border-top: 10px solid #ffffff; overflow: hidden; }
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Make a border transparent by default:

```
.top-bar [...]        {border-top: 10px solid transparent}
.top-bar [...]:hover  {border-top: 10px solid #ffffff}
```

Comment: it's not working..I'm using [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) if it helps..

Comment: Try add this:

.top-bar ul > li:not(.name), .top-bar ul > li:not(.name).active { background: black; border-top: 10px solid #transparent; overflow: hidden; }
.top-bar ul > li:not(.name):hover, .top-bar ul > li:not(.name).active { background: black; border-top: 10px solid #ffffff; overflow: hidden; }

Comment: and should I erase something instead? or just add that one?

Comment: We're getting close to the solution! There's still a little drawback..

[take a look](http://twitpic.com/brwaow)

It shouldn't overflow the bar..

Comment: Ok, try this: .top-bar ul > li a:not(.button) { border-top: 10px solid #transparent; color: white; display: block; font-size: 13px; font-weight: bold; height: 35px; line-height: 45px; padding: 0 10px; }
.top-bar ul > li:not(.name):hover, .top-bar ul > li:not(.name).active { background: black; border-top: 10px solid #ffffff; overflow: hidden; }

Comment: I've ut the latter lines instead of the previous ones and now it looks that way:

[link](http://twitpic.com/brwdyi)

Comment: Ok, now you edit these css lines to make it look as you need.

Comment: I've changed something..you see the error here?

[Image](http://twitpic.com/brwsj1)

there is a red border, when I hover a new white border appears..I'd like to have on ly one border that changes color..here the CSS snippet:

[css code](http://jsfiddle.net/g6UZw/12/)

Comment: I've done it mate..I changed a couple of more things! thanks a lot for your hints (:

Answer (score 0):

Try adding padding to top (10px) and on hover remove the padding and replace it with the border-top: 10px.

So Basically:

```
.top-bar{
padding-top: 10px;
}

.top-bar:hover{
padding-top: 0px;
border-top: 10px solid #fff; 
}
```

Hopefully that will solve the issue,